# Check Reachability of Secure Connection on custom Port on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, reachability

i want to check if an Secure-Connection to an IP-Adress and an custom Port is possible. I checked the Reachability Sample from Apple, but with this i can only check if a Host is reachable.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reachability API is primarily focused on the status of the device's network interfaces, not whether a particular host is available to talk.

The only way to test availability of an IP address and port is to try to establish a connection. Nevertheless, you can integrate it with the reachability API so that you only attempt to connect when there is an interface (wi-fi or cell) that can reach that host.